# .NET Unreal Tournament bots in C# - cannot build Codeplex code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I want to use the Unreal Tournament environment as a playground to develop AI bots in C#. I found a good starting point here [Creating NET bots for UT](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Creating-NET-AI-Bots-for-Unreal-Tournament), however this site is not maintained with lots of dead links. A video on this project [UT3 Bots for .Net](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S2UYqNP_tE) An updated version of the C# code is moved to Codeplex [.NET Unreal Tournament Bots](http://utbots.codeplex.com/). It provides a folder with build process templates and a folder with solutions.

I am unable to build this code. I have no experience with templates, and loading the solution in VS2012 does not build. VS2012 migrates the code to this version with warnings on .NET version 2.0/3.0, but no errors. So I don't think that's fatal.

If I load the solution in VS2012 I get solution mapping errors:

> The mappings for the solution could not be found. [...] The active
>   solution has been temporarily disconnected from source control because
>   the server is unavailable.  To attempt to reconnect to source control,
>   close and then re-open the solution when the server is available.  If
>   you want to connect this solution to another server, use the Change
>   Source Control dialog.

If I try to build anyhow, I get the following build errors:

> 2>D:\Essential\Programming\Visual C#\Unreal tournament\UT Remote
>   bots\UTRemoteBotSolution\UTUserBot2004\RemoteUserBot.cs(189,35,189,43):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UTVector' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [...]
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

All errors seem to point to `UTUserBot2004`, which one of the 4 solutions provided. Two (`UTUSerBot`, `UTRemoteBot`) are targeting UT 1999 Game of the year version, the other two (`UTUserBot2004`, `UTRemoteBot2004`) are aimed at UT 2004. I am only interested in the 1999 GOTY version described in the original Channel9 post.

I assume the code provided is fine, I think it is my lack of experience how to get this code to work is the problem.

Any help to get this code to build would be appreciated.

Comment: You can ignore the Source Control Binding error if you've downloaded the zip file. If you want to get rid of it open file->Source Control->Change Source Control and in the window that opens hit unbind on all projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project you are working with used an older style of compilation, where after a project was done building, it was copied into the bin folder of another project in the solution.  As such, unless your project is in the exact same folder structure (i.e. `E:\Shared Files\Shares\`), it will fail to copy to the right location, and will not be available.  Also, not all the projects were referenced between each other.

To correct this, first go to the Properties of the `UTRemoteBot` project.  On the `Build Events` tab, remove everything in the `Post-Build Event Commands`.  Next, Right Click the `UTUserBot2004` Project, then `Add -> Reference...`  In the solution tab, check the `UTRemoteBot2004` Project.

Also, the project is missing a Reference to `System.Windows.Forms`.  Again, right click `UTRemoteBot` project, `Add -> Reference...` On the Assemblies tab, under Framework, check `System.Windows.Forms`.

The messages relating to Source Control are not an issue, and can be ignored, since you are not making changes to this project to publish back to CodePlex.

Comment: This is good. With these modifications the code compiles and builds. What remains is a whole lot of warnings like_'warning CS1591: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'UTRemoteBot.BotSkin'_ Not sure how that will effect the working, but I will see. Thanks, Jan

Comment: all that really means is that they didn't completely document every public member in their API, but since you are working from the source and not a dll, you don't necessarily have to have the documentation.